# What is the proper method to integrate $x^2e^{-(ax^2)}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What is the proper method to evaluate the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2e^{-ax^2}dx$$ ?

I know that for $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-ax^2}dx$$ we can convert to polar coordinates and then use the [standard trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_polar_coordinates).

Comment: do it by parts.

Comment: @DanielXiang To do it by parts I need a closed form for $\int e^{-ax^2}dx$, which does not exist.

Comment: first write integrang as $xxe^{-ax^2}$ then let $u=x$, $dv=xe^{-ax^2}dx$. Then apply by parts and notice that the integrand is an even function, so you can write $2$ mimes integral from zero to infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying the "standard trick" on your second integral, you get $$f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-tx^2}dx = \sqrt{\frac{{\pi}}{t}}$$Taking derivatives of both sides with respect to $t$ yields

$$f'(t) = \bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-tx^2}dx\bigg)' = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-tx^2}dx= \ \   ...$$

One advantage to this method being that it's easy to calculate 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2n}e^{-tx^2}dx $$ by just taking sucessive derivatives of $f(t)$.

The only downside is that you have to prove that you can put the derivative on the inside of the integral.  This is an easy proof, but only after some machinery is developed.  The proof I know involved the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts.
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-ax^2} dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x d(\frac{-e^{-ax^2}}{2a})dx \\
&= -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{-e^{-ax^2}}{2a} dx + [\frac{-xe^{-ax^2}}{2a}]^{\infty}_{-\infty} \\
&= \frac{1}{2a}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-ax^2} + 0 \\
&= \frac{1}{2a} \sqrt{2\pi \frac{1}{2a}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi/a}}{2a}.
\end{align*}
The fourth equality follows from recognizing $e^{-ax^2}$ as the kernel of a $N(0,\frac{1}{2a})$ distribution.

Comment: I didn't understand your first step. How is $xe^{-(ax^2)}=d(\frac{-e^{-ax^2}}{2a})$ ? Shouldn't it be $xe^{-(ax^2)}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{-e^{-ax^2}}{2a})$ instead?

Comment: yeah, sure. I'm not using formal notation- this notation is useful for me for remembering this technique. You just swing the derivative to the other term, flip the sign, and add the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Let me recall the gamma function which is defined as follow:
$$ \Gamma(n) = \int_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x}dx.$$
Then by symmetry we have
\begin{align}
I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2e^{-(ax^2)}dx &= 2 \int_0^\infty x^2e^{-(ax^2)}dx 
\end{align}
Let $ax^2 = t$. Thus $2axdx = dt$, i.e., $dx = \frac{dt}{2\sqrt{at}}$.
Hence
\begin{align}
I = 2\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-(ax^2)}dx  = 2\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{2a\sqrt{at}}e^{-t}dt
= \frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}} \int_0^\infty t^{3/2 -1}e^{-t}dt =\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{a\sqrt{a}}
\end{align}
Since [$\Gamma(3/2) = \sqrt{\pi}/2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Particular_values), we conclude that
$$ I = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a\sqrt{a}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the "standard trick" (using polar coordinates) can be extended to handle this case as well.
$$
\int x^2 e^{-ax^2}dx\cdot\int e^{-ay^2}dy=\iint x^2 e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}dxdy=\frac{1}{2}\iint (x^2+y^2) e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}dxdy,
$$
where the second equality is by symmetry; so
$$
\int x^2 e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{\iint(x^2+y^2)e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}dxdy}{2\int e^{-ax^2}dx}.
$$
The new double integral can be evaluated in polar coordinates, and the denominator is known.  Indeed, this approach can be used to solve $\int x^k e^{-ax^2}$ for any even $k$.